# Command line FTP - delete all files and folders

Tags: script, ftp, automation

My script looks something like this:

```
ftp -i -d -s:C:\Automation\FTP_Config_Files\FTP.txt
```

My FTP.txt reads like this:

```
open xx.yy.xx.zz
user
password
lcd Z:\
cd /inetpub/wwwroot
mdelete *
mput *
quit
```

Basically I want to delete ALL files and folders (about 10 folders and 25 files) in the `/inetpub/wwwroot` directory, however `mdelete *` is not deleting the directories. Can anyone give any insight on this dilemma I face. I can only do this via cmd for automation purposes (to deter the answers like use FileZilla or CuteFTP).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cd /inetpub/
rm -r wwwroot/
```

This question seems to be a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387151/how-to-delete-folders-with-wildcard-via-cmd-ftp-windows-server-2008).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `MDELETE` is missing a value: try `MDELETE *.*`
(i.e., period between 2 asterisks).